# Window-Size from Resource not possible? - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Small question: If I add a ResourceDictionary to a Window via:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../Dictionaries/MainDictionary.xaml" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And there set a Width and height, it gets ignored at the start of the Window. For example:

```
<Style TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="200" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="400" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="200" />
</Style>
```

As soon as I add the values to the Window directly, it works as expected.
Is this just a limitation of WPF, probably because the Resource-File is loaded later than the Window itself andere there is a Timing-problem, or am I just doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: I see my first part of the answer didn't matter at all, so the only part left can already be found in the duplicate.

Comment: Ok thanks, seems like I searched for the wrong Keywords